# Algorithm to project a point onto a geodesic polyhedron?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, algorithms, computer-vision

I have a geodesic polyhedron/icosphere and would like to map an arbitrary point onto its surface through the origin. I devised the following algorithm:

1. For the point, find the three closest vertices on the geodesic polyhedron.
2. Find the intersection of the line drawn through the point and origin, and the plane mapped out from the three vertices.

Is this algorithm correct?

Is it always true that the closest vertices to a point correspond to the projected point's triangle in a geodesic polyhedron? In other words, is my assumption correct that the point's three closest vertices on the polyhedron correspond to the triangle that the point will be projected onto? I don't see how it couldn't be true, but would like confirmation.

Comment: I think your approach is good, but will need a bit of refinement to handle the case where the line from the origin to the point $p$ passes through a vertex $v$ of the polyhedron. In that case, the result should be $v$, but depending on whether $p$ is inside, outside or on the polyhedron, you will get ties for first or second place when you rank the vertices by their distance to $p$ and if you choose the wrong three closest vertices in your step 1, your step 2 won't work. I'd guess you should test first whether $p$ is a multiple of $v$ for some vertex $v$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that my algorithm is generally OK, but it is slow and vulnerable to numerical errors. Here is something better (although I haven't tested it).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821350/find-the-projection-of-a-vector-on-the-icosahedron-or-on-its-unfolded-surface